# On a variant of the equation $\sigma(x)=2^n$

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials

It is a nice exercise to prove that the only solutions (positive integers $x$)
of the equation on the title
are products of Mersenne primes; with all exponents equal to $1$.

((see also: A046528 in the OEIS))

Question: It is true that the only solutions $A \in GF(2)[x]$ to the equation
$$
\sigma(A) = x^a(x+1)^b
$$
are products of distinct `Mersenne irreducible polynomials` $M$ where this means
$$
M = x^c(x+1)^d+1
$$
and $M \in GF(2)[x]$ is irreducible.

Trivial example:
$$
\sigma(x^2+x+1)=x(x+1).
$$
As usual $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of all positive divisors of the positive integer $n$
and $\sigma(A)$ is the sum of all divisors (including $1$ and $A$) of the polynomial $A$ in $GF(2)[x])$.

Comment: Is this exercise in a book somewhere, so I can refresh my memory on how to go about solving it?

Comment: Just try an induction on $\omega(x)$

Comment: In the OEIS page that I included in the question you may find a link to a proof, but it is amusing to try it yourself!